# What is the k value that splits the region into 2 equal regions?

Tags: calculus

A horizontal line, $y=k$, is drawn through the region formed by the graphs of y=0 and x=0 and $y=2-x^3$ and $y=\cos(x^2)$.

Comment: The two graphs seem to intersect at one point only. There is no region bounded by the curves. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5hkcfvpfox

Comment: I forgot to say when bounded also by the y-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** see the edit at the bottom for a correct solution.

The value you want to find is the $k$ that satisfies

$$ \int_0^k (2-x^3) - \cos(x^2) \,dx + \int_k^{1.26726} (2-x^3) - \cos(x^2) \,dx = \int_0^{1.26726} (2-x^3) - \cos(x^2) \,dx $$

which can be written as

$$ 2 \int_0^k (2-x^3) - \cos(x^2) \,dx = \int_0^{1.26726} (2-x^3) - \cos(x^2) \,dx $$

and $k \approx 0.46585$. To get this value you'll probably need a calculator as the fresnel integral ($\int \cos t^2 \, dt$) doesn't have a closed form, just series representations.

**Edit:** The above finds a vertical line $x=k$, which is not what was originally asked. Below is how to find the horizontal line $y=k$:

We can write the expression for the variable $k$ as,

$$ 2\int_{-0.035}^k \left[(2-x)^{1/3} - \sqrt{\arccos x} \right]\, dx = \int_{-0.035}^2 \left[(2-x)^{1/3} - \sqrt{\arccos x} \right]\, dx $$

Comment: So how do I find that k value?

Comment: @SelenaSandoval do you know how to integrate?

Comment: Isn't that the area between the curves?

Comment: @SelenaSandoval yes it is. See what I added. You'll either need a calculator or a series to approximate the value of $k$.

Comment: Yes I know how to integrate. But isn't 0.912546 the area between the curves?

Comment: @SelenaSandoval woops, my apologies. you're correct, I copied the wrong value off of my scrap sheet.

Comment: $y=k$ is a horizontal line. It seems that you are taking the vertical line $x=k$.

Comment: @CYAries yes i just realized, but I can't delete my answer. So I'll have to correct it.